# NumberFormat Exception Invalid int: "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]" ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Can anyone tell me how to get an int value from ArrayList ?

```
try {

    getitemno = Integer.parseInt(arr.get(index));

    getid =  getitemno;
    new AllRoutesDetails().execute();
    Log.d("id", String.valueOf(getid));
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Array Data

```
"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]"
```

Comment: Show us how is `arr` declared in your code

Comment: Post more details, more code, logcat.... something.

Comment: use: `.indexOf()` like:  `(yourarraylist).indexOf();`

Comment: show full code, and just take arraylist of integer type, so dont need to cast it in integer and you can get direct integer value.

Comment: Could you please show your declaration of the arraylist arr

Comment: This link will be of great help: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: I do not understand people that question and then they forget about the question.....

Comment: ArrayList<String> arr =  new ArrayList<>();
                arr.add((String.valueOf(MainActivity.RouteidArray)));

Comment: @KrunalShah i am copy my another static Array data into current arr then taken out value from a desire index.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int resultedValue = arr.get(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create ArrayList of Integer which do not require type casting:

```
 ArrayList<Integer> al=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=1;i<11;i++)
    al.add(i);
```

For fetching value simply use

```
let position be=0;
int id=al.get(position); or al.get(0);
```